# Using nmerd/kafka-php async send but behavior is not correct

Tags: php, apache-kafka

Async send misses messages. In the case of my testing sending two or three messages async, it appears one message is missing but it shows up in the success log.

I sent two message to kafka and only see one. Then I tried sending three messages and only see two of them. I'm including some comments below above my logs to describe the weird behavior I'm seeing.

```
{
    const LOG_NAMESPACE = 'kafka';
    
    public static function publishAsynchronously($servers, $message, $key, $topic)
    {
        try {
            self::initializeConfig($servers);
            $producer = new Producer(
                function () use ($message, $key, $topic) {
// when I send two messages I only see 1 unique key but I see the log two times.
// when I send three messages I only see 2 unique keys but I see one log once and another log
// twice
                         Logger::quickInfo(
                        'Producer created',
                        [
                            'key' => $key,
                            'message' => $message,
                        ],
                        self::LOG_NAMESPACE
                    );
                    return [
                        [
                            'topic' => $topic,
                            'value' => $message,
                            'timestamp' => time(),
                            'key' => json_encode($key),
                        ],
                    ];
                }
            );

            $producer->success(
                function ($result) use ($message) {
// Here however the messages in the case of the two messages show two unique messages.
// Here the messages in the case of the three messages show three unique messages.
                    Logger::quickInfo(
                        'Successfully posted to Kafka',
                        [
                            'result' => $result,
                            'message_sent' => $message,
                        ],
                        self::LOG_NAMESPACE
                    );
                }
            );

            $producer->error(
                function ($errorCode) use ($message) {
                    Logger::quickError(
                        'Unsuccessfully posted to Kafka',
                        [
                            'errorCode' => $errorCode,
                            'message_sent' => $message,
                        ],
                        self::LOG_NAMESPACE
                    );
                }
            );

            $producer->send(true);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Logger::quickError(
                'Unsuccessfully connected to Kafka',
                [
                    'errorCode' => $e->getCode(),
                    'errorMessage' => $e->getMessage(),
                    'message_sent' => $message,
                ],
                self::LOG_NAMESPACE
            );
        }
    }

    public static function publishSynchronously($servers, $message, $key, $topic)
    {
        try {
            self::initializeConfig($servers);

            $producer = new Producer();

            $producer->send([
                    [
                        'topic' => $topic,
                        'value' => $message,
                        'timestamp' => time(),
                        'key' => json_encode($key),
                    ],
                ]
            );

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Logger::quickError(
                'Unsuccessfully connected to Kafka',
                [
                    'errorCode' => $e->getCode(),
                    'errorMessage' => $e->getMessage(),
                    'message_sent' => $message,
                ],
                self::LOG_NAMESPACE
            );
        }
    }

    protected static function initializeConfig($servers)
    {
        $config = ProducerConfig::getInstance();
        $config->setMetadataRefreshIntervalMs(10000);
        $config->setMetadataBrokerList(implode(',', $servers));
        $config->setBrokerVersion('1.0.0');
        $config->setRequiredAck(1);
        $config->setIsAsyn(false);
        $config->setProduceInterval(500);
    }
}
```